# Why Am I getting this error? Error: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Help with this view. The diagnostics is not clear and I dont know how to fix this erro.

```
import SwiftUI

struct WeeklyView: View {
    @Binding var selectedDays: String
    @Binding var weekDays: [String]
    var body: some View {
        
        let days = Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols
        
        HStack(spacing: 8) {
            
            ForEach(weekDays, id: \.self) { day in
                let index = HabitEntity.weekDays.firstIndex { value in
                    return value == day
                } ?? -1
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(index != -1 ? Color(HabitEntity.habitColor) :
                                .customIndigoMedium.opacity(0.4))
                        .frame(width: 49, height: 49)
                        .opacity(0.4)
                    
                    Text(day.prefix(2))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .padding(.vertical, 12)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        if index !=  -1 {
                            HabitEntity.weekDays.remove(at: index)
                        } else {
                            HabitEntity.weekDays.append((day))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WeeklyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WeeklyView(selectedDays: .constant())
    }
}
```

I keep encountering this error: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report

I am expecting the code to run.

Comment: Hi Romulus, welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of just pasting a large chunk of code, please update your question to include a *minimal* code sample that reproduces your issue. Also it would be helpful to know when you actually get that message and in which line. This will help us a lot in giving a useful answer to your question.

Comment: It is a typo, comment out sections and you'll find the issue. That preview code is very suspicious

Comment: It looks like you are manipulating a static array that is held by ```HabitEntity```. That seems a bit unconventional. It is also not clear, how this update should trigger a change to the view. Please include the implementation of ```HabitEntity``` (and any other code that it depends on).

Comment: I would try an eliminate all of the procedural code (the `if`s).  It would be better to use computed properties or functions on your object.  Abstracting the behaviour into another view that accepts the `HabitatEntity` and the `day` may also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you want to minimise procedural code in SwiftUI views - There is a lot going on under the covers in the view builders, and it can result in the generation of expressions that are too complicated for the compiler to resolve. When this happens you get the error that you are seeing.

You haven't provided all of the information on how your data structures, so I have created some that show how I would approach this problem. (I suspect that maybe you are backing onto Core Data, since you have a `HabitEntity` - I haven't considered that here).

First, define a `Weekday` enumeration and an `Observable` object for your `HabitEntity`. It is important that the entity is observable because you want your view to update when the `weekdays` change

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

enum Weekday: Int {
    case sunday = 0
    case monday = 1
    case tuesday = 2
    case wednesday = 3
    case thursday = 4
    case friday = 5
    case saturday = 6
    
    var shortSymbol: String {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        return calendar.shortWeekdaySymbols[self.rawValue]
    }
    
    static var orderedDays: [Weekday] {
        [.sunday,.monday,.tuesday,.wednesday,.thursday,.friday,.saturday]
    }
}

class HabitEntity: ObservableObject {
    var color: Color
    var name: String
    @Published var weekdays: Set<Weekday> = []
    
    init(name: String, color: Color) {
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }
    
}
```

This is my simple `ContentView` - it just creates a single, static `@StateObject HabitEntity` and passes it to the `WeeklyView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var habit = HabitEntity(name:"Test", color:.blue)
    var body: some View {
        WeeklyView(habit: habit)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This is my implementation of `WeeklyView`

```
struct WeeklyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var habit: HabitEntity
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(Weekday.orderedDays, id: \.self) { day in
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(habit.weekdays.contains(day) ? habit.color :
                                .indigo.opacity(0.4))
                        .frame(width: 49, height: 49)
                        .opacity(0.4)
                    
                    Text(day.shortSymbol)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .padding(.vertical, 12)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        if habit.weekdays.contains(day) {
                            habit.weekdays.remove(day)
                        } else {
                            habit.weekdays.insert(day)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that because I used a `Set<Weekday>` for `weekdays` it is much simpler to check if a weekday is currently selected and to modify the selection.  There is no need to be concerned with `index` or sentinel values (`-1`).

It also helps in SwiftUI to have small view structures - Abstraction makes it easier to follow what is going on.

By introducing a `CirleDayView` we can simplify `WeeklyView` -

```
struct CircleDayView: View {
    var day: Weekday
    var selected: Bool
    var selectedColor: Color
    var unselectedColor:Color = .indigo
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(selected ? selectedColor : unselectedColor)
                .frame(width: 49, height: 49)
                .opacity(0.4)
            
            Text(day.shortSymbol)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .padding(.vertical, 12)
        }
    }
}

struct CircleDayView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CircleDayView(day: .monday, selected: false, selectedColor: .red, unselectedColor: .green)
    }
}

struct WeeklyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var habit: HabitEntity
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(Weekday.orderedDays, id: \.self) { day in
                CircleDayView(day: day, selected: habit.weekdays.contains(day), selectedColor: habit.color)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        if habit.weekdays.contains(day) {
                            habit.weekdays.remove(day)
                        } else {
                            habit.weekdays.insert(day)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note how `CircleDayView` is decoupled from `HabitEntity`